# why the contianer memory limit in cgroup not accurate

Tags: kubernetes

The container set resource limit：

```
resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 1G
      requests:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 1G
```

the cgroup memory limit:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods.slice/kubepods-podaace5b66_c7d0_11e9_ba2a_dcf401d01e81.slice/memory.limit_in_bytes 
999997440
```

1GB= 1*1024*1024*1024=1,073,741,824B

k8s version:1.14.4

docker version:  docker-ce-18.09.6
OS: ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Because you declared a *GibiByte* using the `G` scale: if you expect a *GigaByte*, you should use `Gi`

```
# k get deployments.apps memory -o yaml|grep -i limits -C 1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 1Gi

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods/burstable/pod15dff9ec-7815-48c0-bfce-453be77413ad/memory.limit_in_bytes 
1073741824
```

Comment: Gibi is binary scale: (2^10)^3, while Giga is decimal scale (10^3)^3. Your solution is correct, your explanation isn't ;-) And certain folks still call (2^10)^3 Giga (i.e. GB) instead of Gibi (GiB) - looking at you, MicroSoft. see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-memory

Comment: thank you, the account is  999997440 not 1000000000?

Comment: yeah, that's weird because the byte-based value is correct... need to investigate further! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have performed some tests.

For the values between 999997440 B (976560 KB) and 1000000000 B (as in your example) you will have the same results in memory.limit_in_bytes = 999997440 B.
Till you reach the next (integer) number of bytes divisible by your pagesize (default 4096). In my example it was 1000001536 B (976564K).

I am not linux expert but according to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt):

> A successful write to this file does not guarantee a successful setting of
>   this limit to the value written into the file. This can be due to a
>   number of factors, such as rounding up to page boundaries or the total
>   availability of memory on the system. The user is required to re-read
>   this file after a write to guarantee the value committed by the kernel.

I would like to suggest use Gi notation instead as mentioned by [prometherion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761069/11207414) to have more control about  resources limits.

Hope this help.